# how to change premission of SDCARD to Readwrite in Android 2.2 FileExplorer 

Tags: android

I am  trying to push a videofile onto SDCard . But when I opened SDCARD in FIleExplorer the permission of SDCard is not showing readwrite. How to change SDCard permission to readwrite so that I can push my file into SDCard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Solution to this problem:

Step1:
E:\android-sdk_r06-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools>android create avd -n google_emu 
-t 8
Created AVD 'my_avd' based on Google APIs (Google Inc.),
with the following hardware config:
hw.lcd.density=160

Step2:
E:\android-sdk_r06-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools>mksdcard -l e 512M mysdcard
.img

Step3:
E:\android-sdk_r06-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools>emulator -avd google_emu -sdcard mysdcard.img

After this go to DDms/fileExplorer. In that select "sdcard" and top right press Right Arrow Icon to install the 
corresponding file into SDCard ,which opens up a dialogue box from which we select our file and push it to SDCard.
Now Run your Android project , it will work fine.