# Android - Change Directory Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, sd-card

How can I change the SD Card Permissions to drwxrwx--x currently it is d--------

Please help!

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3746005/940096)

Answer (score 1):

in android `avd manager ->edit->size of sdcard less then 1024mb ->apply->ok`
then run avd